# Excel dependent list best way to sort 2000 records?

Tags: excel, list

I have a data set of 4 columns and around 2000 rows. I need to produce an easy to use dashboard type product so anyone in can filter down to find the relevant record. Think of it as filtering down eg country - region - city - contact person

I have mocked something up using dependent drop down lists using a much smaller data set but it seems hard to scale this up, is there a better way in Excel of doing this?

Comment: Does not the built in filter option work for you ?  Highlight your heading row, Data ==> Filter.  Then just choose what you're looking for ??

Comment: Would you be finding only a **single** row or more than one row.

Comment: @Ditto Yes the filter option works but I want to make a clean dashboard type of excel file so that all the source data is hidden and only 1 record will be displayed at a time as the user selects through each of attributes in sequence. I have the filters added but am not aware that they can be modified to achieve the effect as described?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Yes, the user should just be looking for one row of data. So by the time they have selected from the third column of data they will be left with just one 'answer' from single row. Hope that helps.

Comment: @pnuts I did consider a pivot table and play around briefly. Never actually set one up so wasn't sure if a pivot table was a possible solution for the task described? If that would manage this task better that dependent lists? I ideally want to have the bulk of the data hidden and easy for anyone to use without displaying all the source data to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

PivotTable example, where Data is shown in ColumnsA:E of the same sheet, but could be on a different sheet):

[image: SO28303521 example]

each of `id`, `c`, `r`, `c`, and `p` is in ROWS (in order). Each small `+` and `-` can be expanded/collapsed independently (in the example all are collapsed except `D` and elements within `D`).